# Weka ignoring unlabeled data

Tags: nlp, classification, weka, arff

I am working on an NLP classification project using Naive Bayes classifier in Weka. I intend to use semi-supervised machine learning, hence working with unlabeled data. When I test the model obtained from my labeled training data on an independent set of unlabeled test data, Weka ignores all the unlabeled instances. Can anybody please guide me how to solve this? Someone has already asked this question here before but there wasn't any appropriate solution provided. Here is a sample test file:

```
@relation referents
@attribute feature1      NUMERIC
@attribute feature2      NUMERIC
@attribute feature3      NUMERIC
@attribute feature4      NUMERIC
@attribute class{1 -1}
@data
1, 7, 1, 0, ?
1, 5, 1, 0, ?
-1, 1, 1, 0, ?
1, 1, 1, 1, ?
-1, 1, 1, 1, ?
```

Comment: a) Could you provide a link to the other question you mean? b) What do you mean with "test the model"? What is the output? What output did you expect?

Comment: a) Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876121/classifying-unlabelled-data-in-weka 
b) 'model' refers the model obtained from training data.
The output said: classified instances = 0
                 ignored instances = 5
I expect classified instances  = 5 and a classification accuracy

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link. I'm looking at the source code right now but can't see anything that would lead to the behavior you describe. Also, I was asking what you meant by "test the model", as in "How do you test your model?" Can you give us the source code? Also, if you have missing class labels, you can't compute an accuracy, because you have no ground truth to compare with.

Comment: I meant that I'm looking at the WEKA source code right now, I still need yours, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I use a simple perl script to call Weka using this command: 
system(java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t train.arff -T test.arff > result.txt)
Weka should work without labels because my friends have used the same format in java and it works for them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you specify a *training set* `-t train.arff` and a *test set* `test.arff`, the mode of operation is to calculate the performance of the model based on the *test set*. But you can't calculate a performance of any kind without knowing the actual class. Without the actual class, how will you know if your prediction if right or wrong?

I used the data you gave as `train.arff` and as `test.arff` with arbitrary class labels assigned by me. The relevant output lines are:

```
=== Error on training data ===

Correctly Classified Instances           4               80      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         1               20      %
Kappa statistic                          0.6154
Mean absolute error                      0.2429
Root mean squared error                  0.4016
Relative absolute error                 50.0043 %
Root relative squared error             81.8358 %
Total Number of Instances                5     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 2 1 | a = 1
 0 2 | b = -1
```

and

```
=== Error on test data ===

Total Number of Instances                0     
Ignored Class Unknown Instances                  5     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 0 0 | a = 1
 0 0 | b = -1
```

Weka can give you those statistics for the *training set*, because it knows the actual class labels and the predicted ones (applying the model on the training set). For the *test set*, it can't get any information about the performance, because it doesn't know about the true class labels.

What you might want to do is:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t train.arff -T test.arff -p 1-4
```

which in my case would give you:

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction (feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4)
     1        1:?        1:1       1 (1,7,1,0)
     2        1:?        1:1       1 (1,5,1,0)
     3        1:?       2:-1       0.786 (-1,1,1,0)
     4        1:?       2:-1       0.861 (1,1,1,1)
     5        1:?       2:-1       0.861 (-1,1,1,1)
```

So, you **can** get the predictions, but you **can't** get a performance, because you have unlabeled test data.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense. Thank you so much. One quick question: are the 1 and -1s in the 3rd column the predicted labels of the test data?

Comment: Yes, because the class attribute is nominal, each value is identified by its index (1 and 2), but the actual value (1 and -1) is printed, too. (See weka.classifiers.Evaluation#predictionText). And please don't forget to upvote, I like my points ;)